# Read CSV files and find the same values on the specific columns

Tags: algorithm, csv, search, go

I created a simple command line application to read CSV files in a specific folder and find the same values on the specify column which exists on all files. ([Here's the complete source code.](https://github.com/Gujarats/csv-reader))

Here's the core of the logic:

```
func csvReader(inputColumn, fileLocation string) {
    startTime := time.Now()

    // get all the files from the specific folder
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(fileLocation)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    noColumn := make(chan struct{}, len(files))
    results := make(chan map[string]bool, len(files))

    // reading all the files from dir concurrently
    for _, file := range files {
        wg.Add(1)
        // and read it concurrently to get the data from specific column
        go func(file os.FileInfo) {
            defer wg.Done()
            f, err := os.Open(dir + file.Name())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            datas, ok := readFile(inputColumn, f)

            if !ok {
                noColumn <- struct{}{}
                return
            }

            results <- datas

        }(file)

    }

    wg.Wait()

    // check if we got the column or not
    select {
    case <-noColumn:
        fmt.Printf("The column name = %v doesnt exist\n", inputColumn)
        return

    default: // do nothing and continue
    }

    close(results)
    close(noColumn)

    //receive results and determine which size datas is the smallest
    theSameValue := getSameValues(&results)

    fmt.Printf("final result = %+v\n", theSameValue)
    fmt.Printf("final result size = %+v\n", len(theSameValue))
    fmt.Printf("time consume = %+v\n", time.Since(startTime).Seconds())

}
```

The function is finding the files on specified `fileLocation` and then concurrently reading the file to get the values from the given column `inputColumn`, and passing the values to channel to save the results from reading the CSV files.

The channel `results := make(chan []map[string]bool)` is passed to a function the begin searching the values that exist on all files.

```
theSameValue := getSameValues(&results)
```

Notice that the function `getSameValues()` receives the pointer of results. I did this because I don't' want the `results` channel to be copied to the functions argument which takes resource of memory.

And here is the `getSameValues()` function:

```
// getting the same value from all the datas
func getSameValues(results *chan map[string]bool) []string {
    var datas = make([]map[string]bool, len(*results))
    minIndex := -1
    minSize := int(MaxUint >> 1)
    i := 0
    for values := range *results {
        sizeValues := len(values)
        if sizeValues < minSize && sizeValues > 0 {
            minSize = sizeValues
            minIndex = i
        }
        datas[i] = values
        i++
    }

    // getting the same value from all the datas
    var theSameValue []string
    for value, _ := range datas[minIndex] {
        isExistAll := false
        for _, data := range datas {
            if data[value] {
                isExistAll = true
            } else {
                isExistAll = false
            }
        }

        if isExistAll {
            theSameValue = append(theSameValue, value)
        }
    }

    return theSameValue
}
```

Hopefully this would help others and if you find something that can be improved please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pointers to `chan`

Channel variables are references to an underlying data structure.
As such, in terms of resources, I don't think you gain anything at all by passing a `*chan` instead of the `chan` itself.
I re-read the section on channels in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels),
and there's no mention about saving resources by passing around pointers,
and it's not logical.
So I think you can safely stop using a pointer for this and simplify the code.

#### Likely bug

This can be simplified:

> ```
> isExistAll := false
> for _, data := range datas {
>     if data[value] {
>         isExistAll = true
>     } else {
>         isExistAll = false
>     }
> }
> ```

You can use the value of `data[value]` directly:

```
isExistAll := false
for _, data := range datas {
    isExistAll = data[value]
}
```

But I don't think this code does what you intended.
The value of `isExistAll` will be the value of the last `data[value]`.
I think you want it to be true only of all values are true:

```
isExistAll := true
for _, data := range datas {
    isExistAll = isExistAll && data[value]
}
```

#### Constructing paths

Instead of concatenating strings like `dir + file.Name()` to create paths,
it's better to use `path.Join(dir, file.Name())`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing when using pointer to `chan`. Now I have the answer thanks to you.

Comment: @GujaratSantana ah yes, I meant `isExistAll := true`, fixed it now, thanks!